# How can I hide the controller in a customized route in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a route in my ASP.NET application to handle a specific URL pattern, but I want to make the URL cleaner and hide the controller name. I've defined a route that currently maps URLs like this: `sample.com/controller/thread/id/slug` to the "PersonController" with the "Thread" action.

How can I have URLs like `sample.com/thread/id/slug`?

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Thread",
    url: "{controller}/Thread/{id}/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Thread", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@pooria you can try this code.

and refer this link for more information: http://johnatten.com/2013/08/21/customizing-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/

and you need to create **custom route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "CustomeThread",
        url: "Thread/{id}/{slug}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Thread", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
    );
```

Comment: This code not work ... but i check your link .. thank you